# Using expanded macro as search pattern for \patchcmd

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox, patching

Is there any way to use the value of an expanded macro as the search pattern for `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` (or `xpatch`'s `\xpatchcmd`, etc), so that one can have some sort of a "dynamic" patch, by way of change catcodes?

Here's a minimum working example (MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\wordlist}{cat dog parrot goldfish hamster}

\newcommand\selectpet[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \patchcmd{\wordlist}{#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{}{}
  \wordlist
  \egroup
}

\selectpet{dog}  %% This works

\def\mychoice{dog}
\selectpet{\mychoice}  %% This doesn't

\end{document}
```

Comment: Full expansion or once?

Comment: `\expandafter\selectpet\expandafter{\mychoice}`

Comment: Perhaps this is easier with `expl3` sequences code instead of patching?

Comment: Thanks @percusse, you pointed me in the right direction, and @David hit it on the head! @Christian Unfortunately my `expl3`-fu is not up to scratch at all. :-/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahem... an answer maybe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to expand `mychoice` before calling `\selectpet` so:

```
\expandafter\selectpet\expandafter{\mychoice}
```